# Code Signing on for Linux Platform through electron forge (shows potentially unsafe while installing)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, code-signing-certificate, electron-forge

[image: warning]

I want to make it safe for all user and i am building package through Electron-forge
on officiall site there is code signing guide for macos and windows, i need help for Linux platform (ubuntu)

I tried with **dpkg-sig**

Comment: Related: [How can I remove false warning in electron linux ubuntu app installer?](/q/75142287)

Comment: Yes it's related